# Godot Invalid get index 'Player' on base 'KinematicBody2D'

Tags: gdscript

Ok guys, i just trying to make a function to make a camera like top-down games with rooms, and idk why this appear, can you help me?

[Code and error (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC9Xu.png)

Comment: Show us the parent node for camera.

Answer (score 0):

In your scene 'player.tscn', is the player Node actually named 'Player' or does it still have the default name 'KinematicBody2D'? The actual node needs to be named 'Player' if you want to use the reference you've given above.